# What is wrong in this \author field?

Tags: titles

I can't seem to get Pandoc to render the `\author{}` LaTeX command to a pdf properly. Here is my input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath ,amsthm ,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{An unoffensive title}
\author{Athan Clark \\ url{email@website.com}}
\date{Forever, 2014}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage

Hello world!

\end{document}
```

Am I missing a flag to `pandoc`? My version is fairly recent, it's

```
$~> pandoc --version
pandoc 1.12.2.1
Compiled with texmath 0.6.5.2, highlighting-kate 0.5.5.1.
```

Comment: No, nothing changed unfortunately :/ I might have to settle with pdflatex

Comment: Sorry about that, it's an American (at least, in Colorado) expression to denote compromise. I would rather work with pandoc, but I may have to settle for (pdf)latex. Is pdflatex (as a language standard) a subset / extension on latex? I am still very new and uneducated. In the end, though, I would like to have a pdf file, so I just assumed pdflatex would be the answer to that problem. I would like to keep pandoc for it's AST - I can just write haskell code to make my pipeline.

Comment: Thank you, but that still isn't quite the issue. I'm trying to use pandoc as a replacement for pdflatex. The command I would issue would be `pandoc foo.tex -o foo.pdf` - to convert the LaTeX to a pdf with pandoc. I'd like to keep pandoc because then I can write my scripts in haskell.

Comment: Hmm, well, this is beginning to sound like the question is off-topic for a *TeX-related site (since the file *does* compile normally), but, for the record I can use `pandoc` in exactly the way you want without errors.  Note I'm on an older computer right now, so it is running pandoc version `1.11.1` (installed from the Debian respositories).  I'll try with a newer computer / version of `pandoc` later today.  However, you do know that `pandoc` doesn't *replace* `pdflatex` --- you need to have a "LaTeX system" (e.g., TeX Live) installed?  Pandoc just runs `pdflatex` behind the scenes.

Comment: I actually did not know that! Shoot, well in the case that this is going off topic, I guess we should quit. But I'm trying to learn LaTeX right now so I can use `pdflatex`, I've got some basics stuff working now. Thank you for your help, jon, it means a lot to me that good people like you are here to help newbies :)

Comment: No problem.  And don't forget that you can write simple `markdown` documents (or use `Haddock markup`, etc.) and have `pandoc` *convert* them to LaTeX documents --- just not get a PDF without a TeX system of some kind installed.  That might be useful for learning, at least in the beginning.  (Gonna erase some of my other comments.)

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `\` before `url`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath ,amsthm ,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{An unoffensive title}
\author{Athan Clark \\ \url{email@website.com}}
\date{Forever, 2014}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage

Hello world!

\end{document}
```